# Need emission to NOT cast shadows

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, light

I want light but no shadows using emission lights. Even though I uncheck the Ray Visibility "Shadow" I'm still getting shadows. [image]

[image]

Comment: There's two lights in your scene, un-ticked on both?

Comment: Yes, both are unticked. I quadruple checked.

Comment: Have you tried unticking the shadows on the object?

Comment: Yes.. shadows are UN-ticked on every object. Very bizarre.

Comment: No matter what I do I am STILL getting nasty hard-edged shadows. I attached the blend file above except I forgot to bake the graphic in.. still you can see what I mean.

Comment: Are you sure those are shadows and not reflections?

Comment: Doh! You're right. That's what it must be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## First, the answer to the question:

To get rid of shadows in cycles, you can disable Shadow in the **Ray Visibility** of the object (not the emitter).

[image]

## BUT

Those are not shadows you are looking at, they are reflections of the object itself.

You've created a very reflective, almost mirror like material.

[image]

Without changing the lights, here's a render using a diffuse shader on the object, the alleged shadows are gone....

[image]

Here's the same scene with a glossy only material, showing the reflections on the glossy sirfaces...

[image]