# How can I have a light that casts no shadows?

Tags: shadows

Is it possible to light an object from three locations using emitters but only allow two of those emitters to cast a shadow from the object? I have an emitter from above, right and left. However, I do not want a shadow to be cast from the light on the left but retain the shadows being cast by the other two lights.

Comment: Please specify what render engine you are using.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42183/need-emission-to-not-cast-shadows

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46911/how-can-i-make-a-shadow-disappear-in-cycles/46960#46960

Answer (score 2):

It is possible if you're using lamps, not objects. Simply remove the check for "Cast Shadows" under the lamp material settings.